# merger function in R

Tags: r, read.table

I'm trying to merge two columns with merge(df1,df2,by = ('event')'. These are in CSV. Heres what I have:

```
library(tidyverse)
source.data <-(file.path("C:","Users","Administrator"))
df1 <-read.csv(file.path(source.data, "test1-rstudio.csv"))
df2 <-read.csv(file.path(source.data, "test2-rstudio.csv"))
merge(df1,df2, by("Customer Id"))
```

Comment: I don't see an actual question here...

Comment: I'm getting an error message in merging them.                                                 
      > merge(df1,df2, by("Customer Id"))
      Error in by.default("Customer Id") : 
      argument "INDICES" is missing, with no default
     > merge(df1,df2, by=("Customer Id"))
     Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example? Maybe posting some code that replicates a few rows of df1 and df2 so that we can try the code ourselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that the common column in `df1` and `df2` by which you want to merge is actually `Customer.Id` rather than `Customer Id`.  If so, then the following should work:

```
merge(df1, df2, by="Customer.Id")
```

You may check your column names by using e.g. `names(df1)`.

Note that `by` expects to be assigned via `=` to either a single string common column name *or* a vector of strings.  So either of the following should work:

```
by="Customer.Id"
by=c("Customer.Id")
```

Comment: I tried that and the column is in fact Customer.Id but im still getting the error message that : argument "INDICES" is missing, with no default

Comment: Try using the `all=TRUE` option.

Comment: It isnt working. I get the same error message. I did the print function and verified the datasets loaded correctly as well.                                                        
                                                               
                                                               
   library(tidyverse)
source.data <-(file.path("C:","Users","Administrator")
df1 <-read.csv(file.path(source.data, "test1.csv"))
df2 <-read.csv(file.path(source.data, "test2.csv"))
merge(df1, df2, by("Customer.Id"), all=TRUE)

Comment: @blueshift123 Your syntax is wrong.  You need `by="Customer.Id"` or maybe `by=c("Customer.Id")`.